# Particles effect in react native

Tags: react-native

In the background of my react-native app, I'd want to add a particle effect
Something like this: [particleJs](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/)

I can't find a package for this purpose

can anyone help?

Comment: Did u check out this npm package ? [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-particles)

Comment: Of course, but not the one I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://reactnativeexample.com/react-native-background-particle/), it's not the exact same tho.

```
npm install react-native-particle-background
```

Comment: I'm attempting to use this package, but it takes too many requests for my application, and react-native warns me against using it, which reduces the speed of my app.